# Ensure correspondence between key and value types

Tags: typescript

If I have a type:

```js
interface ITest {
    a: number;
    b: string;
}
```

I may want to defined a function that sets a property on an object with that interface dynamically.

I can get some of the way, however the following code does not seem to properly compare the key and value types:

```js
interface ITest {
    a: number;
    b: string;
}

const item: ITest = {
    a: 1,
    b: 'A Test',
}

const setValue = <K extends keyof ITest>(x: ITest) =>
    (key: K) =>
        (value: ITest[K]) => x[key] = value;
```

Gets part of the way. However, from putting this through the playground, we get inconsisitent results:

```
interface ITest {
    a: number;
    b: string;
}

const item: ITest = {
    a: 1,
    b: 'A Test',
}

const setValue = <K extends keyof ITest>(x: ITest) =>
    (key: K) =>
        (value: ITest[K]) => x[key] = value; 

setValue(item)('a')('test');
setValue(item)('b')(false);    // only this ones shows an error
setValue(item)('b')(1);
setValue(item)('b')('b');      // if properly working, only this will work
```

This seems to imply that the compiler is happy provided `value` is a type of any of the values on `ITest`, which is not quite ideal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition should probably be:

```
const setValue = (x: ITest) =>
    <K extends keyof ITest>(key: K) =>
        (value: ITest[K]) => x[key] = value;
```

which you can test:

```
setValue(item)("a")(3); // okay
setValue(item)("b")("hello"); // okay
setValue(item)("c")(123); // error!
//  ---------> ~~~
// "c" is not assignable to "a" | "b".
setValue(item)("a")("whoops"); // error!
//  --------------> ~~~~~~~~
// "whoops" is not assignable to number
```

The idea is that `setValue` itself is a concrete, non-generic function, but the function that `setValue(item)` returns should be generic in the type `K` of `key`, and then the `value` parameter of the function *that* returns should be constrained to `ITest[K]`.

---

Note that you don't want `setValue` itself to be generic in `K`, or else when you call `setValue(item)`, the type of `K` will be specified already, and then the returned function will be a concrete one of type `(key: keyof ITest)=>(value: ITest[keyof ITest])=>ITest[keyof ITest]`, which allows bad things like `setValue(item)("a")("whoops")`:

```
const badSetValue = <K extends keyof ITest>(x: ITest) =>
    (key: K) =>
        (value: ITest[K]) => x[key] = value;

badSetValue(item)("a")(3); // okay
badSetValue(item)("b")("hello"); // okay
badSetValue(item)("c")(123); // error!
//  ------------> ~~~
// "c" is not assignable to "a" | "b".
badSetValue(item)("a")("whoops"); // okay?!  uh oh
```

---

Also, since `setValue()` is so general in its implementation, you *might* decide you want it to be even more general:

```
const generalSetValue = <T>(x: T) =>
    <K extends keyof T>(key: K) =>
        (value: T[K]) => x[key] = value;
```

which works like `setValue()` on `ITest` objects,

```
generalSetValue(item)("a")(3); // okay
generalSetValue(item)("b")("hello"); // okay
generalSetValue(item)("c")(123); // error!
//  ----------------> ~~~
// "c" is not assignable to "a" | "b".
generalSetValue(item)("a")("whoops"); // error!
//  ---------------------> ~~~~~~~~
// "whoops" is not assignable to number
```

but works equally well on other object types also:

```
const otherThing = { name: "Harry Potter", age: 11 } 
generalSetValue(otherThing)("age")(17); // okay
```

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIBUIGczIN4BQyxycAXMiAK4C2ARtANxEl0U5SgDmzAvgQIQB7EDmTBINChmy4AvPhbFyyAIwAaJcjbIA5AEFkmHLs38Cw0biwQwANTgAbKigUAKAB7TjYAJTI5AD4tAB4AaWQID0gQABMsZABrCABPIRg0H0C3ZJSKMP8grRJkNwA3JxdvWQBtMIBdQsDkDxrc+oDkCucIZgIbe0qINwkIGl83ACI4SYmAZl9GZAB6ZeQhRLgU-tsHHpHJCcm6WamACwhHRyFZpdX1ze2BvZcDsaOEU9UAJgW7tegUCEUAAhAR7sgALTQmEw5oAP0R4LWk0+4gSICEuDgWCwwC4IDgdEcKDAQmQ00myAAPhSTgA6HaDfajcZTGZHADuZyEQgADlhbisAVAgaDkcRYVKpQjEXKkfdJtzeQKqcAMVjSLj8YTiaTydR6NABBYRGI6HBYgBlXZDTrhSLRCBxBK5dKZWTZLwenBNLQ5VL5P0lErlIbVHB1RoBZqtdqdbouPoW622lmHdmnP7Ch5bAgpm3M16so4nI4XK43RY5jZ5gtp4sZ1FfX7V+6A4FgiHS6Wy+ES5voyianF4glEknIMkUmY0umTRn1ovDEuZrk8-mCttrWspAD8IOIVDO6zOJtNVmQXGd0CchZermQIXQXoo6GDJAdURi8SSqXdL4BnkyAFDGxQkGGPRvlGTQtG0qQdAoia9Ca14gLejj3kMbxspS8zbrm2xoRhWHpu8UxluclzXEK9y7gQxFQHeDYrk2nwTD82btqKnYSlCPYCX2A5ouqw7Ytq456lO5KUnOxwLgxN5MZhLE4UcHJTMqm60SKYpdms-ECUZ0J9vK-aKlpqpDpi4ljrqk7ToaDBQIIZq4FiFxQOgZzcJ0eCUHANAQBQkwABJwKKKTIAAClikBQJM6ikNeFCqKoyC8MginocppGvB50Dedw6nXl8ADsBH0QIQA)